# How to sanitize email before mailing with php

Tags: php, email, sanitization

I have a form on a website where the user types a name into the `input` field and a message into `textarea`. This message will be sent to the backend and via php `mail()` - mailed to a specific recipient from my database. Now I'm not sure what sort of sanitisation I should perform before the message is sent. What's the best practice with plain PHP or something like PHPPurifier?

I googled and googled but all I get is how to sanitise email addresses, nothing about the message content and if it's necessary at all.

EDIT: I'm not familiar with what damage can be possibly done with some sort of malicious email body. Stripping all the HTML seems most obvious but anything else? I just really need line breaks mostly I think. What's the common practice here?

I'm not after sanitizing the email address itself, this will come from database.

Comment: It's hard to say what kind of sanitization you could possibly need, if you don't elaborate on the mail bodys content type.

Comment: This may be of use to you: [Email injection](http://www.damonkohler.com/2008/12/email-injection.html). The filter_var() technique is good for the email address, but you'll want to adjust the message part so that no new mail headers can be added from it.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ 
//all good
}
```

ref: [Validate filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

its not fool proof, but probably good enough for most

Comment: `"<script>alert(1)</script>"@example.com` is a valid address.

Comment: This is for validating an email address. He is looking to sanitize the textarea which contains the email message.